# How to query Node.js Express with curl

Tags: node.js, curl, express

I'm going to test via curl a simple application with Nodejs.

curl command is:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "Name"}' http://localhost:3000/users
```

and Node.js runs like:

```
app.post('/users', users.addUser);
```

and somewhere else in users:

```
exports.addUser = function(req, res) {
console.log(req.query);
//etc.
```

output is `{}`. req.body, instead, is undefined.

How can I retrieve that parameters with curl? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read `POST` data with Express, you will have to use `app.use(express.bodyParser());`.

Quoting [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body):

> This property is an object containing the parsed request body. This feature is provided by the `bodyParser()` middleware, though other body parsing middleware may follow this convention as well. This property defaults to `{}` when `bodyParser()` is used.

Although it says Express defaults to `{}` when `bodyParser()` is used, I think that's a typographical error and is the opposite.